# Not able to find Property of a class of wcf service, while invoking service from client

Tags: wcf

I am returning a Hashtable, using a property from a wcf service, but in the client I am not able to find the property, help ME!!

This is my Service side code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
   [OperationContract]
    HashTable_Reference GetParametersWithDesk(String value);

}
[DataContract]
public class HashTable_Reference
{
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    public Hashtable htID
    {
        get { return ht; }
        set { ht = value; }
    }

}
```

This is my Client side code:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
ServiceReference1.HashTable_Reference hr = new ServiceReference1.HashTable_Reference();
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
hr = client.GetParametersWithDesk("Sys12");
```

I need to access or get the Hashtable from the property of hr(object of the class)

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: Also, what would you expect a Java client to do with a `HashTable`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [DataMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) attribute with your property to specifies that the member is part of a data contract.

```
[DataMember]
public Hashtable htID
{
   get { return ht; }
   set { ht = value; }
}
```